# How to pass a list from one class to another in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

So i have a list which i add data to on one screen (every time a certain button is clicked). I then have a bottom naivgation bar which allows me to switch between the screens (there is no pop or push route due to this as well).

My issue is I have two screens. I want to access the list from the first state class inside the second state class.

**Class with the list:**

```
class Security extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecurityState createState() => _SecurityState();
}

class _SecurityState extends State<Security> {

  List<Log> my_logs = []; // i want data stored inside here

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Class where i want to access the list from the previous class:

```
class History extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HistoryState createState() => _HistoryState();
}

class _HistoryState extends State<History> {

  List<Log> items = [] // i want it here
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();

  }
}
```

Is that possible?

Also atm, if i was to switch between the bottom navigatio buttons the list would lose the items that were in it. How would i avoid this also? Could i make a global list inside the main class or something?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Provider then wrap the class where you have the bottom nav bar into the provider, and then you can listen it from any child you want, and also you can update the data and call notifyListener

Comment: most basic aproach whould be to create a new class like class Logs holding the static list of log with methods to operate on list but I also recomend Provider: https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course, that is possible. You can use [app state provider](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) to use a global list, and you can set and get the list from that provider. There is a very helpful blog [here](https://medium.com/codechai/provider-state-management-in-flutter-d453e73537c5).

Your provider will look like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LogProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  List<Log> _logList =
      List<Log>();

  List<Log> get logList =>
      this._logList;

  set logList(List<Log> value) {
    _logList = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }


}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply, I now have a slightly better understanding of providers and their importance. However I have a slight issue. I tried to implement this using the links you gave the list does update, howevver when I switch to a different screen and back the list resets back to the empty state. The code for the LogProvider class where i added an extra add method, and the widget is in this link, https://mystb.in/ScreenSkatingAcid.scala

Comment: You are using unnecessary getList() method in your provider. While calling logList, you can get the list. You should delete getList() from the provider and call it like this: provider.getList[index].

Comment: I did that but still its the same, when switching screens the data from the list is lost. Maybe im getting confused on how i should be adding to the list?

Comment: Can you add your Security page to here, too? https://mystb.in/ScreenSkatingAcid.scala

Comment: I have added it to the bottom of this link. I removed some of the other widgets because it was too long. https://mystb.in/PotentialSallyBegan.scala 
However, i left the button that when its clicked it adds a value to the list in the LogProvider class.

Comment: Hi, so i found my issue, which was that bottom nav bar was disposing on each time i change screen, but thanks a lot for your help. Anyways your answer solved my original question. Have a good day sir!