# How to pass list to another class?

Tags: list, flutter

I have problems wit passing data to another class and trying to solve it.

Basicly I'm getting some values from textfields and storing them in a list.

```
ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text("Add Task"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      itemList.add(
                        ListItems(
                          title: _titleController.text,
                          text: _textController.text,
                          selectedDayTime: _selectedDay,
                        ),
                      );
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    });
                  },
                ),
```

I have also another class to show these items as a listview.Everytime I add new item to the list, I will show this data as listview item. However, I don't know how to pass the itemList from AddTask class to HomePage class.

ListItems class:

```
class ListItems {
  String? title;
  String? text;
  DateTime? selectedDayTime;

  ListItems(
      {required this.title, required this.text, required this.selectedDayTime});
}
```

My question is how can I pass the itemList from AddTask class and use it in my HomePage class.

Comment: In your page contains a listview and floating action button for add task?

Comment: @JahidulIslam I did not create the listview in my HomePage yet. All I want to do is pass the list data from AddTask class to HomePage class so I can start building the listview.

Comment: @JahidulIslam If i can somehow pass the data to my other class, I prob can code the listview part.

Comment: In your home you want to show data. Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right. @JahidulIslam

Comment: You try with state management like provider, bloc or getx, It will solve your problem.Otherwise you store your data to shared preferences and get it from home page.

Comment: @JahidulIslam I could not understand tbh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237300/discussion-between-jahidul-islam-and-sonelektrikci).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64809614/10659482

Comment: @Akif i checked this but could not find how to implement it to my code.

Comment: Connect me and we can look it together.

Comment: @Akif I could not find how to reach you.

Comment: From my profile: https://www.linkedin.com/in/deremakif/